# Error installing linphone-sdk v.4 (Cocoapods) - iOS

Tags: ios, linphone-sdk

Project

- Cordova (platform iOS)
- macOS

Install pod file (linphone-sdk 4.4.35), but I get an error:

`pod install`

```
Installing linphone-sdk 4.4.32
[!] Error installing linphone-sdk
[!] /usr/bin/unzip /var/folders/q8/5fhs5dls3bv3nr0fwwh6gfwc0000gn/T/d20220322-3544-1lttggl/file.zip -d /var/folders/q8/5fhs5dls3bv3nr0fwwh6gfwc0000gn/T/d20220322-3544-1lttggl

Archive:  /var/folders/q8/5fhs5dls3bv3nr0fwwh6gfwc0000gn/T/d20220322-3544-1lttggl/file.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /var/folders/q8/5fhs5dls3bv3nr0fwwh6gfwc0000gn/T/d20220322-3544-1lttggl/file.zip or
        /var/folders/q8/5fhs5dls3bv3nr0fwwh6gfwc0000gn/T/d20220322-3544-1lttggl/file.zip.zip, and cannot find /var/folders/q8/5fhs5dls3bv3nr0fwwh6gfwc0000gn/T/d20220322-3544-1lttggl/file.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Podfile:

```
# DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec.git'
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'my_project' do
    project 'my_project.xcodeproj'
    pod 'linphone-sdk', '4.4.32'
    pod 'linphone-sdk/basic-frameworks', '~> 4.4.32'
    pod 'linphone-sdk/app-extension-swift', '~> 4.4.32'
end
```

Tried it

- reinstall cocoapods, pods
- clear cache

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

In the folder we are looking for your version:

> ~/.cocoapods/repos/linphone-bc-public-podspec/linphone-sdk/

Go to the linphone website with releases. Copy link you version:
https://download.linphone.org/releases/ios/

In file "linphone-sdk/version/linphone-sdk.podspec" search string "s.source" and replace with a new link.